# My contents go out of place when zooming in or out

Tags: html, css, position

everytime i try zooming in or out everything go out of place :/ , or trying to open the page in another browser than google chrome , i tried searching the internet but i didnt understand and i am new to html and css.

Here is my html code and css code :

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.header .bckground {
}
.header {
 height: 70px;
 width: auto;
 background-color: #440e62;
 min-width: 960px;
}
.header h1 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30pt;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 7px;
 font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 float: none;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.nav {
 height: 620px;
 width: 250px;
 border-radius: 0;
 border: 4px solid #440E62;
 float: none;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.nav h3 {
 color: #440E62;
 font-size: 36px;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 text-align: center;
 float: none;
 height: 565px;
 width: 163px;
 margin-top: auto;
 padding-top: auto;
 padding-bottom: auto;
}
.nav h2 {
 color: #440E62;
 font-size: 36pt;
}
.footer {
 width: auto;
 height: 70px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 border: 5px none #440E62;
 background-color: #440E62;
 clear: both;
 float: none;
 min-width: 960px;
}
.bodyy h5 {
 float: right;
 clear: left;
}
.bodyy {
 width: 780px;
 height: 618px;
 float: right;
 clear: none;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-right: 600px;
}
.nav p {
 color: #440E62;
 font-size: 36px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 160px;
 height: 50px;
 background-size: 160px 70px;
 background-position: center center;
 float: none;
 background-origin: padding-box;
 padding-left: 20px;
 position: static;
 padding-right: 20px;
 clear: none;
 top: auto;
 display: list-item;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 margin-left: 40px;
}
body {
 min-height: 100px;
}
.bodyy p {
 font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: left;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
.bodyy img {
 float: none;
 clear: none;
 
}
.bodyy .tagname {
 position: absolute;
 top: 500px;
 left: 1270px;
 color: #440E62;
 font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="p.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div>
<div class="header">
  <h1 align="justify">Pirates Asu</h1>
</div>
<div class="bodyy">
<h1>IT committee</h1>
<p>The IT committe is the strongest committee in pirates ASU , they have the best members and they are going to rock this year</p>
<img STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:100px; LEFT:1200px; WIDTH:400px; HEIGHT:400px"  src="10603764_10203982859144113_8753444382621391138_n.jpg" width="480" height="480" alt=""/>
<p class="tagname">IT Head : Kareem Ahmad</p>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <p>Home</p>
  <p>Commitees</p>
  <p>About us</p>
  <p>Timeline</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously your css. It is so hardcoded with pixels everywhere that things blow apart eventually. 
 Even on my laptop screen with 1366*768 resolution, chrome can't open things properly at 100% zoom,. I had to zoom out to 75% to see it properly.

PS:will eventually post some css edits

---

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="p.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>

        <div class="header">
          <h1 align="justify">Pirates Asu</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="nav">
          <p>Home</p>
          <p>Commitees</p>
          <p>About us</p>
          <p>Timeline</p>
        </div>

        <div class="bodyy">
            <h1>IT committee</h1>
            <p>The IT committe is the strongest committee in pirates ASU , they have the best members and they are going to rock this year</p>
            <img STYLE=""  src="10603764_10203982859144113_8753444382621391138_n.jpg" width="480" height="480" alt=""/>
            <p class="tagname">IT Head : Kareem Ahmad</p>
        </div>

        <p style="clear: both;"></p>

        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

css

```
@charset "utf-8";
.header .bckground {
}
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}

.header {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #440e62;
    min-width: 960px;
}
.header h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30pt;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.nav {
    height: 100%;
    border: 4px solid #440E62;
    float: left;
}
.nav h3 {
    color: #440E62;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav h2 {
    color: #440E62;
    font-size: 36pt;
}
.footer {
    height: 70px;
    border: 5px none #440E62;
    background-color: #440E62;
    min-width: 960px;
}
.bodyy h5 {
}
.bodyy {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.nav p {
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 160px 70px;
    color: #440E62;
    display: list-item;
    font-size: 36px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    top: auto;
    width: 160px;
}
body {
    min-height: 100px;
}
.bodyy p {
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
.bodyy img {
    float: right;
}
.bodyy .tagname {
    float:right;
    color: #440E62;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

Although this still is not very good, it still solved the problem. The problem was that you'd placed `width` on many items in pixels. If you really want widhts, set it in percents. Also, dont make `position: absoulte` a common habit. It only hurts in long run. the `float` property is pretty useful and must be cleared once set.